# Remove rows with zero values on a column when zero appears on all levels of a factor

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I would like to filter out rows with zero values when they appear on all methods for the same team.

For example in the case below `team One` has zero error so rows 1,4,and 7 need to be removed.
So if `alpha=beta=gamma=0` in a particular `team` then those rows with zero should be removed.

```
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| id | team  | error | method |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
|  1 | One   |     0 | alpha  |
|  2 | Two   |   5.7 | alpha  |
|  3 | Three |     0 | alpha  |
|  4 | One   |     0 | beta   |
|  5 | Two   |     0 | beta   |
|  6 | Three |     0 | beta   |
|  7 | One   |     0 | gamma  |
|  8 | Two   |     0 | gamma  |
|  9 | Three |   6.7 | gamma  |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
```

The resulting table should be:

```
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| id | team  | error | method |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
|  2 | Two   |   5.7 | alpha  |
|  3 | Three |     0 | alpha  |
|  5 | Two   |     0 | beta   |
|  6 | Three |     0 | beta   |
|  8 | Two   |     0 | gamma  |
|  9 | Three |   6.7 | gamma  |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming initial dataframe as `df`, filter if any `error` in `team` group is non-zero:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(team) %>% 
       filter(any(error!=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

After grouping by 'team', we can check whether the `sum` of logical vector (`error != 0`) is greater than 0 i.e. at least one non-zero element

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(team) %>% 
   filter(sum(error !=0 ) > 0)
```

Or using the logic with `==`

```
df %>%
   group_by(team) %>%
   filter(sum(error == 0) < n())
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:9, team = c("One", "Two", "Three", "One", 
 "Two", "Three", "One", "Two", "Three"), error = c(0, 5.7, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.7), method = c("alpha", "alpha", "alpha", "beta", 
 "beta", "beta", "gamma", "gamma", "gamma")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I get an error: Evaluation error: Need at least one column for `hash()`.
I do this:
set_a %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  filter(!n_distinct(set_a[error == 0]) > 1)

Answer (score 1):

A short way to do it with base r:

```
subset(df, ave(error, team)!=0)
```

This filters out all `team`s with mean error equal to zero... and may be problematic if, for example, there can be negative values of `error` (say, `c(-1, -2, 3)`).

So a more general case would be

```
subset(df, !ave(error, team, FUN=function(x) all(x==0)))
```

.. or using an idea from akrun's answer:

```
subset(df, ave(error %in% 0, team) < 1)
```